# Converter um documento word(DOC,DOCX) para PFD usando PHP ou JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, conversão, microsoft-word

Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de converter um arquivo Word (.doc,.docx) para um arquivo .pdf usando Php ou JavaScript (ou algo parecido). Por exemplo: o usuário faz o upload de um arquivo .docx que deve ser guardado apenas no formato .pdf --para isso fazer a conversão.

Answer (score 1):

### phpgearbox/pdf

> Requer: http://phantomjs.org

Pode usar o https://github.com/phpgearbox/pdf, deve instalar via composer:

```
composer require gears/pdf:*
```

Depois no seu `composer.json` adicione:

```
"scripts":
{
    "post-install-cmd": ["PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"],
    "post-update-cmd": ["PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"]
}
```

Então após o upload selecione assim:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Upload vem aqui

\Gears\Pdf::convert('<caminho do documento>/documento.docx', '<caminho aonde será salvo o pdf>/documento.pdf');
```

---

### PHPOffice/PHPWord

Pode usar o https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord que suporta diversos formatos:

- odt
- RTF
- Word2007
- HTML
- PDF

Deve instalar via composer:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

Exemplo:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Upload vem aqui

$source = '<caminho do documento>/documento.docx';

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('<caminho aonde será salvo o pdf>/documento.pdf');
```

Comment: Segundo a documentação, é necessário instalar o libreoffice, no caso do phpgearbox. É isso msm?

Comment: @RenanLopes **libre-office-headless** ou **unocon**