# Converter arquivo .docx para .pdf com Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Utilizo Python para automatizar tarefas repetitivas no contexto corporativo.

É possível utilizar a linguagem para converter arquivos `.docx` para o formato `.pdf`?

Comment: Qual o motivo dos Downvotes? Acredito ser uma dúvida pertinente, sem resposta nesse site (mas respondida e bem votada no SOen).

Comment: Respondendo o seu questionamento, se essa pergunta fosse feita antes de 2008 talvez fosse bem aceita pois ainda não existia o GitHub. Mas hoje uma exceção seria uma linguagem que possua  libs de conversão entre formatos triviais. Talvez seja esse o motivo dos negativos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques então não temos motivo pra postar nada aqui, já que existem recursos em outros lugares. Fiz o post por que não encontrei material relacionado EM PORTUGUÊS. A mesma pergunta feita aqui sobre outras linguagens e não foi recebida negativamente.

Comment: Só dei o meu ponto de vista por que encontrei sua publicação sua numa fila de análises para ser fechada. Quanto a não encontrar material a respeito em português aqui no site parece ter já ter bastante material a respeito https://www.google.com/search?q=converter+pdf+em+word+python+site%3Apt.stackoverflow.com quanto as outras linguagens seria bom ter o links.

Comment: @AugustoVasques a pesquisa do link é pra converter PDF pra WORD, não o contrário. Fazendo a [a pesquisa contrária](https://www.google.com/search?q=converter+word+em+pdf+python+site%3Apt.stackoverflow.com&ei=7Rb1Yo3wG9Tu1sQPs6ysiAg&ved=0ahUKEwjNmuOohL_5AhVUt5UCHTMWC4EQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=converter+word+em+pdf+python+site%3Apt.stackoverflow.com&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQ2CJYvzFgvzJoAnAAeACAAVqIAYkHkgECMTGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) temos uma pergunta "me explique esse código", perguntas sobre PHP, JS e C#, mas somente a minha relacionada a Python. E somente a minha negativada.

Comment: @AugustoVasques sobre as outras linguagens, temos [C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316400/convertendo-arquivo-word-para-pdf), [PHP e JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304024/converter-um-documento-worddoc-docx-para-pfd-usando-php-ou-javascript). Enquanto no SO, temos [esse material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python) com 153k visitas. Se há um problema com a minha pergunta, por favor me diga pra eu poder consertar. Só não consigo enxergar.

Comment: Você viu as datas desse material. Naquela eu veria sentido para os dias de hoje é só pesquisar no github mas é só minha opinião. Se não ficou satisfeito você pode fazer uma publicação no [meta] linkando essa pergunta aqui como debate e pergunta específica pedindo a comunidade uma reavaliação da pergunta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Obrigado.

Comment: Caso decida pelo [meta] veja  [O que é o "meta"? Como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Só um conselho não mandatório, vai com calma e apresente a motivação e importância técnica nos dias de hoje dessa publicação, deixando de lado apego emocional. Quem sabe consiga reverter os votos.

Answer (score -2):

### Solução utilizando o Pacote Office (Windows)

O exemplo abaixo utiliza [pywin32](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) para realizar a conversão utilizando o executável do Word.

```py
import win32com.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

entrada = '/arquivo/de/entrada.docx'
saida = '/arquivo/de/saida.pdf'

word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(entrada)
doc.SaveAs(saida, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Importante notar que, no momento, essa solução é exclusiva para sistemas Windows que tenham o Pacote Office (Word) instalado. [Mais informações aqui.](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/16/python-and-microsoft-office-using-pywin32/)

### Solução utilizando LibreOffice

Uma solução que não depende do Pacote Office é a seguinte:

```py
from subprocess import Popen

LIBRE_OFFICE = '/caminho/para/o/executavel/soffice.exe'

arquivo_de_entrada = '/caminho/do/arquivo.docx'
pasta_destino = '/caminho/da/pasta'

p = Popen([LIBRE_OFFICE, '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', pasta_destino, arquivo_de_entrada])
p.communicate()
```

Para sistemas Linux, `soffice` é chamado diretamente:

```py
from subprocess import Popen

arquivo_de_entrada = '/caminho/do/arquivo.docx'
pasta_destino = '/caminho/da/pasta'

p = Popen(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', pasta_destino, arquivo_de_entrada])
p.communicate()
```

### Solução utilizando [aspose-words](https://blog.aspose.com/pt/2021/10/27/convert-word-to-pdf-in-python/)

A biblioteca `aspose-words` fornece métodos simples pra fazer essa conversão.

```py
import aspose.words as aw

entrada = '/arquivo/de/entrada.docx'
saida = 'arquivo/de/saida.pdf'

doc = aw.Document(entrada)
doc.save(saida)
```

### Material complementar

- [Converting docx to pdf with pure Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982064/converting-docx-to-pdf-with-pure-python-on-linux-without-libreoffice)
- [.doc to .pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)
- [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score -2):

Há ainda a possibilidade de utilizar o "pandoc". NO Windows, há um instalador, no Linux, basta fazer "sudo apt-get install pandoc".

Seja como for, o seu uso é assim:

pandoc arquivo.docx -o arquivo.pdf --metadata title="Título do Documento" --metadata author="Autor do Documento" --toc --standalone -V lang="pt-br"

Essa seria uma forma possível de chamar, mas com os dois primeiros parâmetros já funciona.

O pandoc é muito poderoso. Converte para várioos formatos: html, wiki, markdown, docx, pdf, epub entre vários outros.

Para usar a conversão para pdf, você deve também instalar o pacote texlive-base.

Comment: É uma boa informação adicional (pra quem prefere usar uma CLI), mas a pergunta especificou o uso de Python. Talvez seja possível editar a resposta para que sua solução seja aplicada no contexto de um script Python.